# JavaScript Behavior difference: IE11/Edge vrs Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript

```
function displayInfo(nKey) {
    var i, xdata, xfilm, xprop;
    if(!nKey) return false;
    var objFilm;
    var imgRef;
    //iterate through all object properties; display their attributes
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON('dbMovies.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.disc, function(i, xdata) {
            if(xdata.key == nKey) {
                objFilm = xdata.film;
                imgRef = xdata.img;
                if(xdata.doc) bkDoc = true;
                return false;
            }
        });    // $.each
    })
    .done(function() {
        // objFilm has either a single film object or else an array of film objects
        var arInfo = [];
        if(!$.isArray(objFilm)) {
            var arProps = Object.keys(objFilm);....//absolutely
            arProps.forEach(function(item) {
                if(item != "ref") {
                    arInfo.push(item + ": " + objFilm[item] + "<br>");
                } else {
                    arInfo.push(item + ": <a href=" + objFilm[item] + " target=_blank>Wikipedia</a>");
                }
            });

    var w = window.open('', '', 'width = 650, height = 500, resizable');
    $(w.document.body).html(arInfo.join(""));
    })  // .done
```

I have what we'll call a kiosk app that contains the contents of my film library as stored in a JSON file. One can access the contents in several ways, but each yields a display of all relevant titles. For example, searching for films with Sophia Loren, one would see this result:
[image]

All browsers work to this point.
You can see that each film has a link that leads to certain information about the film.
[image]
Although one browser (Mac Safari) reportedly does not display the Wikipedia link, all other browsers do. But only the Microsoft browsers (Edge, IE11) show the associated thumbnail. Therefore(?), only the Microsoft browsers respond to a click by invoking my display engine on the full version of the image. All browsers respond well and equally on more direct invocations of the display engine. For example, see [http://www.michaelbroschat.com/LongviewChristmas/LongviewChristmas.html].
The information window is created dynamically upon clicking the index number link shown in the first illustration.

All browsers successfully create the new window and most of the information data items. In fact, Chrome and Firefox appear to create the image display code but don't act upon it.
The entire app can be seen at http://www.michaelbroschat.com/film/disccatalog.html
I would love to know why Chrome and Firefox don't allow what the Microsoft browsers allow.

Comment: Why did you replace spaces with `.`?

Comment: I get an error in the browser console in Firefox. Have you investigated that?

Comment: I see no code at all that tries to add an image thumbnail after each film stanza.

Comment: Also, it looks like you return the whole database with each search. You could make things more efficient by just loading the database once when you load the page.

Comment: There's no point in creating a "snippet" if it's completely unusuable unrunnable and incomplete code - just use a code block instead - I removed the leading .'s and turned the snippet into a code block - but the code is still incomplete and syntactically incorrect - but that's up to the OP to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out of your question a critical part of the code, that being the code that creates the `<a>` tag around the image reference.

The problem you're having is that you're stuffing the assembled HTML for the list of films into that popup window, which is opened with no URL reference. Your `<img>` tags are built with relative URLs (like "liners/i0001.jpg"), but since there's no base URL for the browser to reference the image can't be loaded.

Internet Explorer may be making some inference that the popup window has the same base URL as the parent, but other browsers apparently don't do that.

Comment: It took more URL specification than I've had to use in any similar case but by so filling the URL, it all seems to work. My HREF/IMG spec has two levels. First is the specification of the thumbnail. That gets handled with the IMG spec. Second is the call to my display engine, which must also specify the target image to be displayed. 
Thanks!

Comment: (continuing) Here is what I ended up with (incl the original): // arInfo.push("<br><a href=../mpv/mpv2.html?pic=../film/" + imgRef + "&color=#FDFFB6&backcolor=#888&caption=&cc=#EEEED1 target=_blank><img src=" + imgRef + " width=600></a>");  arInfo.push("<br><a href=http://www.michaelbroschat.com/mpv/mpv2.html?pic=http://www.michaelbroschat.com/film/" + imgRef + "&color=#FDFFB6&backcolor=#888&caption=&cc=#EEEED1 target=_blank><img src='http://www.michaelbroschat.com/film/" + imgRef + "' width=600></a>");

Answer (score 0):

I have some theories on this portion of your code:

```
............arProps.forEach(function(item) {
................if(item != "ref") {
....................arInfo.push(item + ": " + objFilm[item] + "<br>");
................} else {
....................arInfo.push(item + ": <a href=" + objFilm[item] + " target=_blank>Wikipedia</a>");
................}
............});
```

ONE: Be sure the anchor tag is using single quotes or double quotes depending on your preference when you output the source such as:

```
<a href="path/to/objFilm/item" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
```

My guess is that being only your version of safari is having an issue with the Wikipedia link it is sensitive to the quotes.

As far as the image goes, where is the **img** tag to output an image path?

Comment: Thanks. These two answers give me much to work with.

Comment: Please see my answer to Pointy. But in general HTML5 no longer requires around the content of an HREF reference. My experience suggests that more than a space character can force that requirement, however.